# How to save an output of airodump-ng to a file?

Tags: io-redirection, stdout, output, fifo, airodump-ng

I've tried to get a file from airodump-ng via redirecting a output stream via:

```
airodump-ng mon0 2>&1 | tee file.txt
```

but this appends to a file rather than rewrites it. So after that I've tried to redirect an output to other output stream via a fifo pipeline:

First terminal:

```
mkfifo fifo1
echo "while [ 1 ]; do cat ~/fifo1 2>&1 | tee file.txt done" > readfifo.sh
chmod +x readfifo.h
xterm -e readfifo.sh
```

Second terminal:

```
airodump-ng mon0 2>&1 > fifo1
```

And in the result we have an appending file.txt, but why ?
How to have only the output of a terminal in the file, but not append to it ?
Is it possible to filter an output of airodump-ng while writeting to a file ?

Best regards,
V7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check

```
man airodump-ng.
```

You want the `-w` option.

```
airodump-ng -w myOutput --output-format csv mon0
```

Generates a `.csv` file of the screendump with the output from `airodump-ng` one line per station.

Comment: Thank you @bu5hman. I've already found an answer and wanted to delete a question, but you've wasted some time to answer so I won't delete it. :)

Comment: Very good of you. `man` is usually a good place to start in. Good idea to read it and play with the options just to see what they do. Have fun.